# Hyphenation Ancient Greek

Tags: hyphenation, greek

I am trying to hyphenate some texts in Ancient Greek in order to count the number of unique syllables (so I want to have every word forcefully hyphenated). I have read that hyphenation patterns in Latex work well with https://ctan.org/pkg/elhyphen, and the examples I saw in the documentation are actually correctly hyphenated.

However, when I try to hyphenate myself (in TexShop), I get a very poor result. I am very new to Latex and probably doing something wrong.
Here is the code I use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek]{babel}

\usepackage{multicol}

% very narrow columns!
\columnsep=2cm
\textwidth=\dimexpr7\columnsep+8pt\relax
\hfuzz=\maxdimen

\begin{document}
\begin{greektext}
\begin{multicols}{8}

Ὅτι μὲν ὑμεῖς, ὦ ἄνδρες Ἀθηναῖοι, πεπόνθατε ὑπὸ τῶν 
ἐμῶν κατηγόρων, οὐκ οἶδα· ἐγὼ δ' οὖν καὶ αὐτὸς ὑπ' αὐτῶν 
ὀλίγου ἐμαυτοῦ ἐπελαθόμην, οὕτω πιθανῶς ἔλεγον. 

\end{multicols}{8}
\end{greektext}
\end{document}
```

And here is the output I get (most word hyphenated incorrectly, some of errors marked):[image]

I have tried to use the available hyphenation patterns to hyphenate in R (here's my solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75043053/hyphenation-for-ancient-greek-in-r), but the result is equally poor. What am I doing wrong? Are there any patterns I am missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

You can get more extensive patterns using a Unicode TeX.

This is with LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek]{babel}

\usepackage{multicol}

% very narrow columns!
\columnsep=2cm
\textwidth=\dimexpr7\columnsep+8pt\relax
\hfuzz=\maxdimen

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{8}

Ὅτι μὲν ὑμεῖς, ὦ ἄνδρες Ἀθηναῖοι, πεπόνθατε ὑπὸ τῶν 
ἐμῶν κατηγόρων, οὐκ οἶδα· ἐγὼ δ' οὖν καὶ αὐτὸς ὑπ' αὐτῶν 
ὀλίγου ἐμαυτοῦ ἐπελαθόμην, οὕτω πιθανῶς ἔλεγον. 

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

---

or with 1sp columns to make sure you catch all hyphens

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek]{babel}

\usepackage{multicol}

% very narrow columns!
\columnsep=2cm
\textwidth=\dimexpr7\columnsep+8sp\relax
\hfuzz=\maxdimen
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{8}

Ὅτι μὲν ὑμεῖς, ὦ ἄνδρες Ἀθηναῖοι, πεπόνθατε ὑπὸ τῶν 
ἐμῶν κατηγόρων, οὐκ οἶδα· ἐγὼ δ' οὖν καὶ αὐτὸς ὑπ' αὐτῶν 
ὀλίγου ἐμαυτοῦ ἐπελαθόμην, οὕτω πιθανῶς ἔλεγον. 

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I was thinking to pack the text into `\showhyphens`, but this is slicker.  Are you sure the columns are narrow enough though?  I'm not literate in ancient Greek, but I would have thought the last item in the first column could be hyphenated, although there may not be a relevant pattern.

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes I wondered about that, a column width of `1sp` is safer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton updated

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Wow, yes, it is now 100% correct! Thank you so much for your help.