No ancient greek minuscules in footnotes with fontspec in LuaLaTex
I'm new with LuaLaTex and eledpar. I work by with try and error - surely an expert will get grey hairs seeing me working.
But eledpar does what I want: greek text on the left page and translation on the other side.
There's only one problem with the footnotes: Greek majuscules (and all latin characters) are shown, but no minuscles.
E.g.pic from footnote #2: "2 add. Π(ῶς ὁ ἥλιος λαμπρυνθήσεται);
What can I do? Thank you for any answer.
%LuaLaTex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\babelprovide[import]{ancientgreek}
\babelprovide[import]{polytonicgreek}
\babelprovide[import]{greek}
\babelfont[ancientgreek]{rm}{SimonciniGaramondPro}
\babelfont[polytonicgreek]{rm}{SimonciniGaramondPro}
\babelfont[greek]{rm}{SimonciniGaramondPro}
\usepackage[series={},nocritical,noend,nofamiliar,noledgroup,noreledmac]{eledmac}
\usepackage{eledpar,hyperref}
\usepackage{metalogo}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pretolerance -1
\hbadness=10000
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}


\begin{document}
\title{Johannes von Damaskus\\

Drei Predigten \textit{Über die Entschlafung der Gottesgebärerin}}
\date{}
\maketitle

\begin{pages}
\fontspec{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
 \pstart 
 \eledsection{ΛΟΓΟΣ ΠΡΩΤΟς ΕΙΣ ΤΗΝ ΚΟΙΜΗΣΙΝ}
 \pend
\pstart
\textbf{ Ἰωάννου.}\\

α'. Μνήμη, ἀληθινήν;\\
\pend
\endnumbering

\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
 \pstart 
 \eledsection{ERSTE PREDIGT}
 \pend
\pstart
1. \ledrightnote{Prov 17,7}{„Das Gedenken der Gerechten geschieht mit Lobliedern“}, sagte der äußerst weise Salomon. „Wertvoll ist angesichts des Herrn der Tod seiner Frommen“ \\

\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages} 
\Pages

\begin{pages}
\fontspec{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{Leftside}

\beginnumbering
\pstart 
\eledsection{ΛΟΓΟΣ ΔΕΥΤΕΡΟΣ}
\pend
\pstart
\textbf{Τοῦ αὐτοῦ λόγος δεύτερος.}\\

α'. Ἔστι μὲν ἀνθρώπων οὐδεὶς, πρὸς ἢν ἅπας ἵεται λόγος σοφοῦ καὶ διάνοια.\\
\pend
\endnumbering

\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
   \pstart
    \eledsection{Zweite Predigt}   
     \pend
   \pstart
1. Es gibt keinen Menschen,Gedanke des Gottweisen zustrebt. \\

\textit{Einzug der Gottesmutter in den himmlischen Tempel}\\

2. Heute wird die  Sich Selbst zum unumgrenzten Orte habend.\\

\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages} 
\Pages

\begin{pages}
\fontspec{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{Leftside}
\fontspec{Linux Libertine O}

\beginnumbering
   \pstart 
    \eledsection{ΛΟΓΟΣ ΤΡΙΤΟΣ}
    \pend
   \pstart
\textbf{Τοῦ αὐτοῦ λόγος τρίτος.}\\

α΄. Ἔθος ἐστὶ ἐμπορευόμενος. \\
Σπάνη\footnote{Σπάνις} γὰρ ἡμᾶς, ὡς ὁρᾶτε, κατειλήφει τῶν ἐδωδίμων. Διὸ δὴ σχεδιάζω τὴν πανδαισίαν, εἰ καὶ μὴ πολυτελῶς, μηδὲ ἀξίως τῆς κεκληκυίας, ἀλλά γε τὴν πεῖναν ἀναγκαίως δυναμένην παραμυθήσασθαι. Οὐ γὰρ αὕτη τῶν ἔγκωμίων προσδεὴς τῶν παρ᾿ ἡμῶν, ἀλλ᾿ ἡμεῖς τῆς παρ᾿ αὐτῆς δόξης ἐπιδεεῖς. Τὸ γὰρ δεδοξασμένον πῶς δοξασθήσεται;\footnote{ add. Πῶς ὁ ἥλιος λαμπρυνθήσεται;} Ἡ πηγὴ τοῦ φωτὸς, πῶς φωτισθήσεται; Ἀλλ᾿ ἡμῖν αὐτοῖς, δι᾿ ὧν δρῶμεν, πλέκομεν στέφανον. Ζῶ γὰρ ἐγώ, λέγει Κύριος, καὶ\footnote{ add. } τοὺς δοξάζοντάς με δοξάσω. \\

εʹ. Δεῦτε, πάντες νοερῶς ᾧ ἡ δόξα καὶ τὸ κράτος, σὺν τῷ ἀνάρχῳ Πατρί, καὶ τῷ παναγίῳ καὶ ζωοποιῷ Πνεύματι, νῦν, καὶ ἀεὶ, καὶ εἰς τοὺς σύμπαντας καὶ ἀτελευτήτους αἰῶ νας τῶν αἰώνων. Αμήν.\\
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}

%\def\printlinesR#1|#2|#3|#4|#5|#6|#7|{\begingroup
% \setprintlines{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}%
% \ifl@d@pnum #1\fullstop\fi
% \ifledplinenum \linenumr@p{#2}\Rlineflag\else \symplinenum\fi
% \ifl@d@ssub \fullstop \sublinenumr@p{#3}\fi
% \ifl@d@dash \endashchar\fi
% \ifl@d@pnum #4\fullstop\fi
% \ifl@d@elin \linenumr@p{#5}\Rlineflag\fi
% \ifl@d@esl \ifl@d@elin \fullstop\fi \sublinenumr@p{#6}\fi
%\endgroup}
%\let\ledsavedprintlines\printlines

\beginnumbering
  \pstart
   \eledsection{Dritte Predigt} 
  \pend
\pstart

\textbf{Dritte Predigt desselben über die Entschlafung der allheiligen Gottesgebärin.}\\

   1. Üblich ist für Verliebte, und geistliche Nachspeise. \\
   Denn, wie ihr seht, mangelt es uns an solcher Nahrung. Deshalb bereite ich eine Stärkung vor, die zwar weder sehr aufwendig noch des Anlasses würdig ist, aber hoffentlich den Hunger stillen kann. Nicht Sie braucht unser Lob, sondern wir sind es, die Ihre Herrlichkeit brauchen. Wie kann man denn die Herrlichkeit verherrlichen oder die Quelle des Lichts erleuchten? Wir erwerben uns damit einen Siegeskranz. \ledleftnote{1 Sam 2, 30}{„Ich lebe, sagt der Herr“; „und ich werde diejenigen verherrlichen, die mich verherrlichen“. \\
   Es ist wirklich köstlich, Wein zu trinken und Brot zu essen. 
   \ledleftnote{Vgl. Ps 103, 15}{\textit{Das eine erfreut, das andere stärkt das Herz des Menschen}}. Doch was ist lieblicher als die Mutter meines Gottes? Sie hat meinen Geist gefangen und meine Zunge in Dienst genommen. An Sie denke ich im Wachen und im Schlafen. Sie, des Logos Mutter, leitet mein Wort. den Sohn Gottes und unseren Gott, unsere Erlösung bewirkt hat. Ihm sei Ruhm und Majestät, mit dem ungeschaffenen Vater und dem allheiligen und lebensspendenden Geist, jetzt und für immer, durch alle Ewigkeiten. Amen.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages} 
\Pages
\end{document}


Thank you for you for helping a beginer. Now all ok?

Thank you for being patient with me. I hope no the code shows the problem.

your example produces the error ! Missing } inserted. <inserted text>                  } l.141 \endnumbering

TeX warns Missing character: There is no ς (U+03C2) in font [lmroman12-bold]:mapping=tex-text;! you need to select a font other than latin modern for Greek text, you need to mark up the Greek section as you have specified the main language is German

Ok, thank you. Why is there another font for the footnotes as for the text?
Where can I chance the font for the footnotes?

Why not using Linux Libertine (or, better, Libertinus) as the main font for everything? Mixing Latin Modern, Simoncini Garamond and Libertine doesn't seem a good typographical choice.

Thank you, egreg, but how? I'm not using \fontspec{Linux Libertine O}?

you should not use \fontspec in a document except in very special circumstances,  it is a low level font selection not really for use within a document.

any reason not to use reledmac which is the newest of these packages, as far as I know?

I want two facing parallel pages in ancient greek and german. Does it work with reledmac?


Don't ignore warnings. You have an error from a missing } and lots of warnings that Latin modern does not have Greek. You need to tell LaTeX which are the Greek sections with \selectlanguage{greek} or other babel commands,
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\babelprovide[import]{ancientgreek}
\babelprovide[import]{polytonicgreek}
\babelprovide[import]{greek}
\babelfont[ancientgreek]{rm}{Arial}
\babelfont[polytonicgreek]{rm}{Arial}
\babelfont[greek]{rm}{Arial}
\usepackage[series={},nocritical,noend,nofamiliar,noledgroup,noreledmac]{eledmac}
\usepackage{eledpar,hyperref}
\usepackage{metalogo}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pretolerance -1
\hbadness=10000
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}


\begin{document}
\title{Johannes von Damaskus\\

Drei Predigten \textit{Über die Entschlafung der Gottesgebärerin}}
\date{}
\maketitle

\begin{pages}
\fontspec{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
 \pstart 
 \eledsection{ΛΟΓΟΣ ΠΡΩΤΟς ΕΙΣ ΤΗΝ ΚΟΙΜΗΣΙΝ}
 \pend
\pstart
\textbf{ Ἰωάννου.}\\

α'. Μνήμη, ἀληθινήν;\\
\pend
\endnumbering

\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
 \pstart 
 \eledsection{ERSTE PREDIGT}
 \pend
\pstart
1. \ledrightnote{Prov 17,7}{„Das Gedenken der Gerechten geschieht mit Lobliedern“}, sagte der äußerst weise Salomon. „Wertvoll ist angesichts des Herrn der Tod seiner Frommen“ \\

\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages} 
\Pages

\begin{pages}
\fontspec{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{Leftside}

\beginnumbering
\pstart 
\eledsection{ΛΟΓΟΣ ΔΕΥΤΕΡΟΣ}
\pend
\pstart
\textbf{Τοῦ αὐτοῦ λόγος δεύτερος.}\\

α'. Ἔστι μὲν ἀνθρώπων οὐδεὶς, πρὸς ἢν ἅπας ἵεται λόγος σοφοῦ καὶ διάνοια.\\
\pend
\endnumbering

\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
   \pstart
    \eledsection{Zweite Predigt}   
     \pend
   \pstart
1. Es gibt keinen Menschen,Gedanke des Gottweisen zustrebt. \\

\textit{Einzug der Gottesmutter in den himmlischen Tempel}\\

2. Heute wird die  Sich Selbst zum unumgrenzten Orte habend.\\

\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages} 
\Pages

\begin{pages}
\fontspec{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{Leftside}
\fontspec{Linux Libertine O}

\beginnumbering
   \pstart 
    \eledsection{ΛΟΓΟΣ ΤΡΙΤΟΣ}
    \pend
    \pstart
    \selectlanguage{greek}
\textbf{Τοῦ αὐτοῦ λόγος τρίτος.}\\

α΄. Ἔθος ἐστὶ ἐμπορευόμενος. \\
Σπάνη\footnote{Σπάνις} γὰρ ἡμᾶς, ὡς ὁρᾶτε, κατειλήφει τῶν ἐδωδίμων. Διὸ δὴ σχεδιάζω τὴν πανδαισίαν, εἰ καὶ μὴ πολυτελῶς, μηδὲ ἀξίως τῆς κεκληκυίας, ἀλλά γε τὴν πεῖναν ἀναγκαίως δυναμένην παραμυθήσασθαι. Οὐ γὰρ αὕτη τῶν ἔγκωμίων προσδεὴς τῶν παρ᾿ ἡμῶν, ἀλλ᾿ ἡμεῖς τῆς παρ᾿ αὐτῆς δόξης ἐπιδεεῖς. Τὸ γὰρ δεδοξασμένον πῶς δοξασθήσεται;\footnote{ add. Πῶς ὁ ἥλιος λαμπρυνθήσεται;} Ἡ πηγὴ τοῦ φωτὸς, πῶς φωτισθήσεται; Ἀλλ᾿ ἡμῖν αὐτοῖς, δι᾿ ὧν δρῶμεν, πλέκομεν στέφανον. Ζῶ γὰρ ἐγώ, λέγει Κύριος, καὶ\footnote{ add. } τοὺς δοξάζοντάς με δοξάσω. \\

εʹ. Δεῦτε, πάντες νοερῶς ᾧ ἡ δόξα καὶ τὸ κράτος, σὺν τῷ ἀνάρχῳ Πατρί, καὶ τῷ παναγίῳ καὶ ζωοποιῷ Πνεύματι, νῦν, καὶ ἀεὶ, καὶ εἰς τοὺς σύμπαντας καὶ ἀτελευτήτους αἰῶ νας τῶν αἰώνων. Αμήν.

\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}

%\def\printlinesR#1|#2|#3|#4|#5|#6|#7|{\begingroup
% \setprintlines{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}%
% \ifl@d@pnum #1\fullstop\fi
% \ifledplinenum \linenumr@p{#2}\Rlineflag\else \symplinenum\fi
% \ifl@d@ssub \fullstop \sublinenumr@p{#3}\fi
% \ifl@d@dash \endashchar\fi
% \ifl@d@pnum #4\fullstop\fi
% \ifl@d@elin \linenumr@p{#5}\Rlineflag\fi
% \ifl@d@esl \ifl@d@elin \fullstop\fi \sublinenumr@p{#6}\fi
%\endgroup}
%\let\ledsavedprintlines\printlines

\beginnumbering
  \pstart
   \eledsection{Dritte Predigt} 
  \pend
\pstart

\textbf{Dritte Predigt desselben über die Entschlafung der allheiligen Gottesgebärin.}\\

   1. Üblich ist für Verliebte, und geistliche Nachspeise. \\
   Denn, wie ihr seht, mangelt es uns an solcher Nahrung. Deshalb bereite ich eine Stärkung vor, die zwar weder sehr aufwendig noch des Anlasses würdig ist, aber hoffentlich den Hunger stillen kann. Nicht Sie braucht unser Lob, sondern wir sind es, die Ihre Herrlichkeit brauchen. Wie kann man denn die Herrlichkeit verherrlichen oder die Quelle des Lichts erleuchten? Wir erwerben uns damit einen Siegeskranz. \ledleftnote{1 Sam 2, 30}{„Ich lebe, sagt der Herr“; „und ich werde diejenigen verherrlichen, die mich verherrlichen“.} \\
   Es ist wirklich köstlich, Wein zu trinken und Brot zu essen. 
   \ledleftnote{Vgl. Ps 103, 15}{\textit{Das eine erfreut, das andere stärkt das Herz des Menschen}}. Doch was ist lieblicher als die Mutter meines Gottes? Sie hat meinen Geist gefangen und meine Zunge in Dienst genommen. An Sie denke ich im Wachen und im Schlafen. Sie, des Logos Mutter, leitet mein Wort. den Sohn Gottes und unseren Gott, unsere Erlösung bewirkt hat. Ihm sei Ruhm und Majestät, mit dem ungeschaffenen Vater und dem allheiligen und lebensspendenden Geist, jetzt und für immer, durch alle Ewigkeiten. Amen.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages} 
\Pages
\end{document}

I used a different font (Arial) for Greek as I didn't have the one you used.

Don’t ignore warnings deserves repeating many times over!

@David Carlisle, thank you very much, you have solved my problem. The only change I made is taking (Linux Libertine O) instead of Arial.

@RaphaelBlasberg so you could have a single setmainfont{Linux Libertine O} and use same font for latin and greek scripts and remove all the \fontspec  commands I guess.

I don't think this is the intended usage of \babelprovide since there's a greek.ldf? (I know it's in the question.)

@David Carlisle, if you have time and this is the right place, could you please help me with two other problems:

to insert greek and german hyphenation patterns in LuaLatex (I found this, but don't know how to install it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/670996/hyphenation-ancient-greek)
to make more space between the sidenotes? Would be great.


@RaphaelBlasberg don't ask new questions as comments, make a new (smaller, but complete) example of your new question and post a new question. although for the hyphenation question that should be answered already by the answer here, so long as you have german as the main language and mark up Greek with \selectlanguage then the appropriate hyphenation rules will be used.
